# Using mmap to allocate double 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, double, mmap

I am attempting to use mmap to create/access twi different (N+2)*(N+2) 2D array of doubles, so that multiple threads can look at their own portion of it and change it, applying the changes so that all others can see. Here is what I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numProcs = atoi(argv[2]);

    int ARRAY_SIZE = (N+2)*(N+2)*sizeof(double);

    double **grid = (double **) mmap(NULL, ARRAY_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (grid == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error mmapping grid\n");
    }
    double **newGrid = (double **) mmap(NULL, ARRAY_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (newGrid == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error mmapping grid\n");
    }
```

When I run it, or try to access anything in it, I get a segmentation fault. I tried to allocate memory as well, with:

```
for(i = 0; i < N+2; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N+2; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < N+2; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N+2; j++) {
        newGrid[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

But I am met with: error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'void *'
      newGrid[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(double));

I believe I am missing something here with how mmap works, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: what does grid[0] contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If N is a compile-time constant or if your compiler supports variable length arrays (VLAs), then you could simply do:

```
double (*grid)[N+2] = (double (*)[N+2]) mmap(NULL, ARRAY_SIZE, ...

grid[4][5] = 2.0;  // setting an element
```

If N is not constant and your compiler doesn't support VLAs, then you need to manually offset:

```
double *grid = (double *) mmap(NULL, ARRAY_SIZE, ...

grid[4 * (N + 2) + 5] = 2.0;  // setting the same element using manual offsets
```

Comment: This was fantastic! A great explanation (along with the one below too!) of how it could be better accomplished. I've implemented this and everything seems to be perfect now, so I thank you! :)

Comment: How can I specify the type when the array goes into a method?. It ends up being incompatible with double**

Comment: @alecardv Yeah, its type is definitely not `double **`.  It's either `double (*)[N+2]` or `double *`, depending on which example you follow.

Answer (score 3):

An array, or an array of arrays, is a contiguous area o memory. A "2d array" using pointers to pointers" is *not* contiguous.

Lets look at some "images" for comparison:

A proper array of arrays looks something like this in memory:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----+----------------+--------------+-----+------------------+
| matrix[0][0] | matrix[0][1] | ... | matrix[0][N-1] | matrix[1][0] | ... | matrix[M-1][N-1] |
+--------------+--------------+-----+----------------+--------------+-----+------------------+
```

On the other hand, a matrix using pointer to pointer looks something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| matrix[0] | matrix[1] | matrix[2] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
 |           |           |
 |           |           V
 |           |           +--------------+--------------+-----+
 |           |           | matrix[2][0] | matrix[2][1] | ... |
 |           |           +--------------+--------------+-----+
 |           |
 |           V
 |           +--------------+--------------+-----+
 |           | matrix[1][0] | matrix[1][1] | ... |
 |           +--------------+--------------+-----+
 |
 V
 +--------------+--------------+-----+
 | matrix[0][0] | matrix[0][1] | ... |
 +--------------+--------------+-----+
```

As you can see they memory layout is quite different, which is why you can't use one as the other.

Comment: I learnt this in the first month I was programming in C, in a hard way.

Comment: That makes sense. If so, do you have any ideas on a possible implementation of this instead?